# Condition with using geometry OLD and NEW

Tags: postgis, geometry, conditional, trigger

Is there a posibility to use a condition with OLD and NEW parameters?
Using postgres 12, and pgAdmin
Geometry in Qgis

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER abc_trigger 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
ON "Table1" FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE abc();
```

Funcion

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
BEGIN
CASE TG_OP
     WHEN 'INSERT' THEN
     WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN
           IF OLD.stat <> NEW.stat OR OLD.geom <> NEW.geom THEN 
                NEW.sum = (
                    SELECT COUNT(ot.id)
                    FROM other_table AS ot
                    WHERE ST_Intersects(st.geom, NEW.geom)                  
            );
         IF OLD.stat <> NEW.stat THEN
              UPDATE Table SET "sumary" = NEW.sumary WHERE Table."stat"=NEW.stat ;      
         END IF;

    WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
END CASE;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

What I need to do.
I`m count value for all table when table is UPDATE. But I want to do it only when row change stat or change geometry...
Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: postgis is for QGIS i am using 3.12 version

Comment: AGAIN! i have solucion, my self
IF OLD.stat<> NEW.stat OR ST_Area(OLD.geom) <> ST_Area(NEW.geom) THEN

Comment: then add it as an answer so other people can find it and up vote it for you